# Numpy multiply each column of array A by the corresponding row of array B, without looping

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have two 2-d arrays, A and B. A is of size 3x3 and B 3x5. I would like to np.dot the 1st column of A (size 3x1) with the 1st row of B (size 1x5), and the 2nd column of A with the 2nd row of B and so on. And return a list of 2d arrays of 3x5 2d arrays, with all the results How should this be done without using Python loops?

My current solution is this, is this ideal?
(a.T[:,:,np.newaxis])*(b[:,np.newaxis,:])

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to compute the inner product `dot`, but the outer product `outer`. So here is a solution with one loop:

```py
[np.outer(A[:, i], B[i, :]) for i in range(A.shape[1])]
```

Is this ok, or do you need to avoid this loop as well? It might get rather complicated, since the handy function `outer` always flattens the input arrays...